# Telegram BOT track who add a user

Tags: bots, telegram

I'm creating a telegram bot. I need to keep track when a user is added and who added it.
How can I do it using the telegram APIs?

Comment: Post your problem clearly and also paste tried code here

Comment: Added where? To Group or Channel?

Comment: @IgorYalovoy To a Group. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Takeda925 Any update on this? I can see it's possible to check for new group members using: `new_chat_members` but can't tell if it gives info on _who_ added them. Will have to test I guess...

Answer (score 0):

In groups with the Telegram API, you can call the `new_chat_members` message and store the user information into an array or DB.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api